# HTML2PDF < sign is not working in php

Tags: php, html2pdf, xhtml2pdf

I have exported data in PDF it is working fine for me, but for one string the text is "`test<5`", when i export this text in PDF it is just showing me "test" in PDF after `<` sign all the text getting blank, can anyone please tell me how can i resolve this issues ? I am using `HTML2PDF` for export data in PDF

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr',true, 'UTF-8');
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
$html2pdf->writeHTML('test<5');
$html2pdf->Output('e-Voucher.pdf');
```

Comment: Full code required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing to HTML, hence the `writeHTML` function. In this case you want to encode the character so it can be interpreted as HTML.

One way of doing this is:

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr',true, 'UTF-8');
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
$html2pdf->writeHTML("test&#x3c;5");
$html2pdf->Output('e-Voucher.pdf');
```

Or as Aleksandar said:

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr',true, 'UTF-8');
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
$html2pdf->writeHTML("test&lt;5");
$html2pdf->Output('e-Voucher.pdf');
```

My output to both:

[image: test<5 example]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `<` is special character in HTML. Instead of `<`, use `&lt;`.